# Chrome extension desktop notification in a separate HTML

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script>
       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var $ajaxData =  xhr.responseText;  
                var hidden = document.createElement ( 'div' );
                hidden.id = 'hiddenel';
                $("body").append ( hidden );
                $("#hiddenel").html ($ajaxData);
                var $aa = $("#hiddenel").find('div .somediv');

                var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                                    'some msg',
                                    'some msg',
                                     $aa.html());
                notification.show();

                } else {
                 alert("Unable to connect...");
                }
              }
            }
            var url = some url;;
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.send();
      });
    </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Now here in this desktop notifiaction I am getting an html with tags.I want to remove those tags that is,I want to replace $aa.html with an html page.
But If I put this script in another HTML then how to communicate and what changes I have to make in manifest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to pass data is just by using url parameters:

```
webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('notification.html?data=' + escape(data)).show();
```

Then on a receiving end I just use [jQuery URL Parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) to parse url parameters.

PS. Looking at your code I would suggest to put jquery.js into extension folder and include it instead, that way it would load much faster.

Also if sole purpose of this piece of code:

```
var hidden = document.createElement ( 'div' );
hidden.id = 'hiddenel';
$("body").append ( hidden );
$("#hiddenel").html ($ajaxData);
```

just to be able to run `$("#hiddenel").find('div .somediv');`, then you can rewrite all that with:

```
var $aa = $($ajaxData).find('div .somediv');
```

Comment: createHTMLNotification() has been depreciated, this no longer works.

Comment: Please be aware that there is currently a Chromium issue to remove this functionality from Google Chrome. http://crbug.com/137297